# c# recursive search to check for a file extension

Tags: c#, file, search, recursion

I want to check if a file in the directory I pass has a specific extension.

```
 public static bool ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory)
 {
     // Process the list of files found in the directory.
     string[] fileEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
     foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
         if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower().Contains(pattern)) 
             return true;

    // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
    string[] subdirectoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
    foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
        return ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);

   return false;
  }
```

call from:

```
bool foundPattern = false;
//recursive search - based on search pattern 
if (System.IO.File.Exists(myDirectory) && System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myDirectory).Contains(pattern))
{
     // This path is a file
     foundPattern = true;
}
else if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(myDirectory))
{
     // This path is a directory
     foundPattern = ProcessDirectory(myDirectory);
}
```

The thing is, I don't get some results (I get false even when there are files with extension .xzz, assuming that I ask for extension .x in the search pattern - sometimes I get true, sometimes I get false).

If I step through it looks like I am looking at directories and going into them recursively and going through files...

But it doesn't.

Comment: Use the overload of `GetFiles` that does the recursion for you: `Directory.GetFiles("*.x*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

Comment: What is the search pattern that you are using? Is it `*.x*`?

Comment: who is "pattern" in you method code? I don't see it declared or passed as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a bug in your code:

```
// Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
string[] subdirectoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
    return ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
```

Should be something like:

```
// Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
string[] subdirectoryEntries = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
    if (ProcessDirectory(subdirectory))
        return true;
```

Otherwise you're only returning the results for a single subdirectory.
It's the same kind of loop you have in the beginning of your function.  You do it right the first time.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do can be easily be done with this

```
string path = @"C:\temp\";
string extension = "*.txt";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, extension);

//or recursivly
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

In your case:

```
public static bool ProcessDirectory(string startPath, string pattern)
{ 
    return Directory.GetFiles(startPath, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any();
}
```